# What happened to Cuusoo set #6

Tags: set-numbering, ideas

Lego Cuusoo just announced set #7 Ghostbusters 30th anniversary.  Cuusoo set #5 is the Curiousity Rover.

Why is there no set #6?  What happened to it or did Lego announce it and then change their minds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like LEGO switched up the numbering of the CUUSOO/Lego Idea sets.  The Ghostbusters set is officially #006 as can be see on the Lego.com site and now that review units of the Exo-Suit have been released to several Lego related blog sites, it has the number #007 on it.

[Official LEGO Shop listing of Ghostbusters set](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Ghostbusters-Ecto-1-21108) Click on the box image

[Review of Exo Suit](http://brickset.com/article/11698/review-21109-exo-suit-part-1)

[Hi Res shot of Exo Suit box](https://www.flickr.com/photos/brickset/14416987088)

Comment: [Time lapse of Tommy Williamson (BrickNerd) building the ExoSuit.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tv4wjI1bRTI) So looking forward to August 1.

Answer (score 7):

The sixth LEGO CUUSOO set is the upcoming Exo Suit. See announcement here: http://blog.lego.cuusoo.com/2013/10/21/results-of-winter-spring-summer-lego-reviews/